# How do i interpolate over multiple keyframes?

Tags: animation, keyframes

How can I use the Interpolation modes like Bezier not just from one keyframe to the next but from e.g. keyframe 1 to keyframe 3 while still going to the place of keyframe 2 without messing with timing?

[image]

Comment: Hello, it's not clear what you mean, if there's a keyframe #2 then keyframe #2 will be played

Comment: well i can set the interpolation of keyframe one to be bezier then the animation will start slow then speed up then slow down again before the next keyframe. However i want it to only start slowing down at keyframe 3 or 4 or 5 instead of the very next one.

Comment: You can set it the way you want in the Graph Editor

Comment: maybe provide a file with a simple example, like an animated cube and the 3 keyframes you're talking about, and tell what you want to do?

Comment: not sure how to upload files here but i made a short gif : https://gifyu.com/image/Sc6iK          i want this path to be one smooth acceleration

Comment: Maybe also share the file? https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: It should work with this kind of curve in the Graph Editor: https://zupimages.net/up/23/31/flok.jpg

Comment: You can move your keyframes, or add another one between two other to control how things happens between them... Whatever fits your needs. You can also use the breakdowner operator to create breakdown keys.

Comment: well yeah it would work with the graph editor but that would mean editing 6 graphs per keyframe per animation since im not trying to animate a cube in one dimention.                   As for L0Lock i dont understand how that helps my problem. Any additional keyframe have their own interpolation right? And the breakdowner things dont allow me to create new poses from what i can tell only shift between two which is just another way to time two keyframes but not more then two right?

Comment: I think I finally figured what you mean, and what you want to achieve is the default behavior: https://i.stack.imgur.com/f9aN6.gif Do you see how it doesn't make a stop at the top, but continues to move? If this is what you want, then you likely changed the default behavior somehow and we can help if you share your .blend in the mentioned blend-exchange

Comment: Okay your right. And when moving in one direction with bezier interpolation that does work. Though my question and example where somewhat lacking cause i didnt expect it to work like this. See what im trying to do is have the objects velocity not slow down regadless of changing directions. I also dont understand why when i reproduce your example but then change the interpolation to anything else it starts stopping in the middle.

Comment: You can't avoid stopping when changing directions, when you consider a single axis, because the velocity has to go through 0: https://i.imgur.com/XVNImwr.gif Perhaps you want a solution where the pathing changes (in the example the cube would start going e.g. a little up, then make a turn, going a little down...)

Comment: Do you mean you cant avoid as in blender cant? Because i just want constant acceleration. In your gif here the cube slows down before the turning point and then speed up after it stopped. What i want is that the acceleration just keeps going. Picture one blade of a rotor. Its changing direction constantly but still constantly accelerating. I have seen one way of doing this using a curve and telling the bone to follow said curve but i cant imagine there not being a way to just tell blender to use this keyframe as just a inbetween pose.

Comment: So you want constant magnitude of your acceleration but changing direction. The thing is, in order to go through given points, at a given time, you would need to calculate a path that satisfies those needs, and I think that's not trivial…

Comment: mhh but how do ppl animate circular motions using ik then? there gotta be some fast solution to this.

Comment: This commentary is getting out of hand :) . @hurensohn Please edit your original question with as clear a description as you can make of the ***final effect*** you are looking to achieve, in one case. The more general explanation of the meaning of interpolation modes will emerge from that, I'm fairly sure.

Comment: @hurensohn I'm bad with armatures but consider how a sine and cosine go through 0, and yet together they draw a circle…